# Docker/Dockerfile: Using ENTRYPOINT for git clone

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to run a git clone command inside my Dockerfile as entrypoint so that it is not cached and I am guaranteed to have the most up to date source code. Currently I have the following code in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
MAINTAINER Fernando Mayo <fernando@tutum.co>, Feng Honglin <hfeng@tutum.co>

# Install packages
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get -y install vim supervisor git curl unzip apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 pwgen php-apc php5-mcrypt php5-mysql php5-curl&& \
  echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf


# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN composer global require "laravel/installer"
ENV PATH ~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH

# Add image configuration and scripts
ADD start-apache2.sh /start-apache2.sh
ADD start-mysqld.sh /start-mysqld.sh
ADD run.sh /run.sh
RUN chmod 755 /*.sh
ADD my.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
ADD supervisord-apache2.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord-apache2.conf
ADD supervisord-mysqld.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord-mysqld.conf
ADD php.ini /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
ADD 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf


# config to enable .htaccess
RUN a2enmod rewrite


# Copy over private key, and set permissions
ADD .ssh /root/.ssh


# Get aws stuff
RUN curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"
RUN unzip awscli-bundle.zip
RUN ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws

# Clone the repo
RUN rm -rd /var/www/html
RUN git clone ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/Laravel /var/www/html
# Set file permissions
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/storage 
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache


# Environment variables to configure php
ENV PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE 10M
ENV PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE 10M




EXPOSE 80 3306
CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

To remove the cache I changed the following lines:

```
# Clone the repo
RUN rm -rd /var/www/html
RUN git clone ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/Laravel /var/www/html
# Set file permissions
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/storage 
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache
```

with

```
# Clone the repo
RUN rm -rd /var/www/html
ENTRYPOINT git clone ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/Laravel /var/www/html
# Set file permissions
ENTRYPOINT chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/storage 
ENTRYPOINT chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache
```

I can build this Dockerfile but when I run it stops before I can do anything (I can't access it with localhost and I don't see any errors). What am I doing wrong with ENTRYPOINT?

Answer (score 1):

Your entry point just does one thing and exits. You probably want to run your server in your entry point so the container sticks around. In your case, it seems like you want to run `run.sh`.

Additionally, only one `ENTRYPOINT` is allowed. You should convert your multiple entry points to a script and use that as the entry point. From the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint):

> Only the last `ENTRYPOINT` instruction in the Dockerfile will have an
>   effect.